# PHPMailer 6.0.5 not working after fresh download from GitHub - Syntax error

Tags: smtp, syntax-error, phpmailer

I've just updated my company html website with a fresh version of PHPMailer.php downloaded from GitHub.

The website has a SSL certificate installed.

With the previous version (5.3) everything was working properly.

I've updated the contact.php page with the new attributes (removed class as suffix)

This is the log error message:

> [Thu Nov 08 17:55:34 2018] [warn] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx] mod_fcgid:
>   stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in
>   /var/www/vip2/sites/vip3157348/httpd/htdocs/functions/phpmailer/PHPMailer.php
>   on line 304, referer: https://www.sqprofessional.com/contact.html

That's the code at line 304:

```
public $SMTPOptions = [];
```

I can't get why I got a syntax error when I didn't change any part of the code on the specific file (PHPMailer.php). I've also tried with a 6.0.4 version of the file but with the very same error code.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It’s because you are running it on a version of PHP is too old. As the read me and other documention says, PHPMailer 6.x requires at least PHP 5.5, but you should be running 7.2 if you’re doing any new development.

Comment: Ok,
thank you very much. Do you know where I can find a compatibility chart?

Comment: There isn't one. PHPMailer prior to 6.x works on PHP 5.0 and up. From 6.x it requires 5.5. That's all there is to it, and it's mentioned in the readme. You should not be using such an old version of PHP; it's unsafe and [unsupported](https://secure.php.net/eol.php).

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm contacting the hosting provider right now.

Thanks again.